# How to assign URLs to docker containers

Tags: docker

I have a couple containers running on my host (Ubuntu Server), and I can access them on my network via host:port.  I'm trying to use containers to replace IIS, so I'm trying to figure out how to assign hostnames to which the containers would respond, but I'm coming up short.  Is there a way to have each container respond to the same ports (e.g., `container1.example.com`, `container2.example.com`), or does this necessitate some sort of appliance or reverse proxy sitting in front to forward from `name.example.com` to `host:port`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you *do* want to put a reverse proxy in front, but you can do that with a container as well:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

This also means you don't need to map the ports of the other containers to the host, just the one for the reverse proxy.

Comment: For plain docker, jwilder/nginx-proxy is what most people seem to use.